# Raspberry Pi 3 Linphone Calling

Tags: pi-3, python, linux, sip

So I am working on a project where I have to be able to make sip calls to a raspberry pi 3 and have it automatically answer any incoming calls. I have been reading this guide: https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Linphone/Linphone%20and%20Raspberry%20Pi/.
But when trying to run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linphoneCall.py", line 17, in __init__
    callbacks = linphone.Factory.get().create_core_cbs()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Factory'
```

If anyone knows how to fix this issue or can recommend me a method of making sip calls through code automatically on the pi, I would appreciate it very much. Thanks

Comment: Did you name your script 'linphone'? Python cannot handle scripts that have the same name as a module you try to import. Or there could be module version issue.

Comment: Python version issue?

Comment: I have tried with python version 2.7.13 and I named the script linCall.py so I don't think that should cause any problems with the module.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same project today, here is how I did it.

1. boot the Raspberry Pi in the lastest version of Raspbian
2. click on the raspberry icon at the top-left corner, then click "Add/Remove Software"
3. type "linphone" in the search bar. You will see a package called "SIP softphone-graphical client". Install that package.
4. find linphone in /usr/bin, execute it in terminal
5. everything is set up in a nice GUI beyond this point. I tweaked the setting for a bit and was able to call my raspberry pi from my phone. Note the auto answer feature is located in "preferences"